# Is deliberate radio interference a crime?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, radio, fcc, communications-law

I know that it is forbidden by FCC regulations to deliberately interfere with radio communications, but is it a crime?

Answer (score 18):

Yes. [47 U.S. Code § 333](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/333) (part of the Communications Act of 1934 as amended) bans willful or malicious interference. [§ 501](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/501) imposes a general penalty for any violation of the Communications Act that doesn’t have a different penalty defined elsewhere in the Act. A first offense is a misdemeanor punishable by up to a $10,000 fine and/or up to a year in jail. Subsequent offenses are felonies punishable by up to 2 years in prison.

In practice, this might result in only a civil action by the FCC. But it is forbidden by Congress and can be punished by imprisonment.

Comment: Isn't it the case that some communications, for example under Part 15, may have to accept any interference that may occur? In that case, would such interference be criminal?

Comment: @JimMack: "Harmful" interference is nevertheless prohibited in [47 CFR 15.5](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-A/part-15/subpart-A/section-15.5)(b). Harmful interference is [defined](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-A/part-15/subpart-A/section-15.3) as "Any emission, radiation or induction that endangers the functioning of a radio navigation service or of other safety services or seriously degrades, obstructs or repeatedly interrupts a radiocommunications service operating in accordance with this chapter."

Comment: report your local authorities for jamming and intercepting cell phones on their own choice ✌

Answer (score 10):

**United Kingdom**

It is an **offence**: the [Wireless Telegraphy Act 2006](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/36/section/68) states

> **68 Deliberate interference**
>
> (1) A person commits an offence if he uses apparatus for the purpose of interfering with wireless telegraphy.

About the possibly narrow definition of [Wireless Telegraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_telegraphy), this [section of the Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/36/section/116) says

> **116 “Wireless telegraphy”**
>
> (1) In this Act “wireless telegraphy” means the emitting or receiving, over paths that are not provided by any material substance constructed or arranged for the purpose, of energy to which subsection (2) applies.
>
> (2) This subsection applies to electromagnetic energy of a frequency not exceeding 3,000 gigahertz that —
>    (a) serves for conveying messages, sound or visual images (whether or not the messages, sound or images are actually received by anyone), or for operating or controlling machinery or apparatus; or
>    (b) is used in connection with determining position, bearing or distance, or for gaining information as to the presence, absence, position or motion of an object or of a class of objects.

Comment: Is voice communication (radiotelephony) included, or only Morse or digital communication (the normal meaning of radiotelegraphy)?

Comment: Not sure, but I would think disruption of any wireless signal.

Comment: @Someone Does [section 116](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/36/section/116?timeline=false) assist? ss115 and 117 also..?

Comment: @Rick thanks, I'll add that to the answer (I tried looking at the The Radio Equipment Regulations 2017).

Comment: I just searched the Act's top-line contents page for "interpretation" (also "meaning" and "definitions" as terminology is not consistent)

Comment: I notice that UK law doesn't seem to have caught up with gender neutral pronouns yet.

Comment: @WeatherVane the act is nearly 20 years old.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. A violation of basically any FCC regulation is a criminal offense under either [47 U.S.C. § 502](https://casetext.com/statute/united-states-code/title-47-telecommunications/chapter-5-wire-or-radio-communication/subchapter-v-penal-provisions-forfeitures/section-502-violation-of-rules-regulations-etc) or [47 U.S. Code § 501](https://casetext.com/statute/united-states-code/title-47-telecommunications/chapter-5-wire-or-radio-communication/subchapter-v-penal-provisions-forfeitures/section-501-general-penalty):

> Any person who willfully and knowingly does ... any act ... in this chapter prohibited or declared to be unlawful ... shall, upon conviction thereof, be punished for such offense, for which no penalty (other than a forfeiture) is provided in this chapter, by a fine of not more than $10,000 or by imprisonment for a term not exceeding one year, or both

And jail time is doubled for repeat offenders.

> Any person, having been once convicted of an offense punishable under this section, who is subsequently convicted of violating any provision of this chapter punishable under this section, shall be punished by a fine of not more than $10,000 or by imprisonment for a term not exceeding two years, or both.